# Minimal set cover

Tags: geometry, number-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, clustering

Let $J = \{j_n\}_{n=1}^N$ be a finite set of non-negative real numbers, and $ \Delta j \geq 0$. I want to find the smallest subset $J_s =\{j_i\}_{i=1}^M \subset J$ such that for every $j_k \in J$ there exists a $ j_l \in J_s $ such that $ |j_k - j_l| \leq \Delta j$.

Example: Let $J = \{1,2,3,5,7,8,12\}$ and take $\Delta j = 1.2$. Then 
$J_s = \{2,5,7,12\}$ solves the problem. (Also $J_s = \{2,5,8,12\}$. )

Does anyone here know on how to solve this, or any equivalent problems? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can always brute-force your solutions from $\emptyset$ to $J$.  Then prune out search trees that cannot yield a valid result.

Comment: Your definition of $J_s$ seems to imply that you're looking for consecutive elements in $J$ starting at $j_1$? Or can $J_s$ be any minimal arbitrary subset that satisfies the condition?

Comment: $J_s$ should only consists of elements from $J$.

Comment: That it works :) the set $J$ is small, $10^3$ elements, so speed is not a big issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort all the elements of $J$; this can be done quickly in $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ time. Reindex the elements of $J$ so that $j_1 \leq j_2 \leq \dots \leq j_N$.

Next, for each $j \in J$ define $S_j = \{ j' : |j-j'| \leq \Delta j\}$. We can think of $S_j$ as being the set of elements that each $j$ *covers*. We then pick $J_s$ in the following manner: first we find the rightmost $j$ such that $S_j$ covers the leftmost element in $J$. This $j$ will be included in $J_s$. We then look at the element that follows the last element in $S_j$ (call it $j'$) and repeat the process as if $j'$ were the leftmost element in $J$. Keep repeating this process until all the elements of $J$ are covered.

This webpage has a more thorough pseudocode if you're interested: http://www.cs.yorku.ca/~andy/courses/3101/lecture-notes/IntervalCover.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great!